# Can`t mount drive on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mount, hard-drive

yesterday I changed the permissions (0440) of an ubuntu server, on all of the files, and now I cant do anything with that, so I took the drive out and now I am trying to mount that drive on another machine running ubuntu server 20.04, but the dribe is not mounting and its giving me this error:

```
root@romania1:~# mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt/old
mount: /mnt/old: special device /dev/sdb3 does not exist.
```

This is the fdisk message:

```
root@romania1:~# fdisk -l /dev/sdb
The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will be used.
Disk /dev/sdb: 447.1 GiB, 480070426624 bytes, 937637552 sectors
Disk model: LOGICAL VOLUME  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 8D7918A9-E547-4030-B36B-C786A0BE0065

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1     2048      4095      2048     1M BIOS boot
/dev/sdb2     4096   3149823   3145728   1.5G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb3  3149824 937633791 934483968 445.6G Linux filesystem
```

I only need the data from this drive. How can I mount this drive or if there is any way to fix the permissions on the old drive?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What is the exact command you used to change the drives permissions?

Comment: I used # chmod  -R 0440 /

Comment: You have broken your system. There are several dozen specialized permissions formerly used by the system that you have smashed to a single, incorrect, permission (`0440`, `r--r-----`). You need eXecute permission on directories to search them. Inspect `sudo journalctl  /dev/sdb`.